# Hi. i'm trying to use material design floating button. For this I added a CDN link. But when i added that, my navbar is disarranged

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

Here is the head in master page where i added the link:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<!-- this is the link -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('vendor/adminlte/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('vendor/adminlte/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('vendor/adminlte/vendor/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css') }}">

@if(config('adminlte.plugins.select2'))
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css">
@endif

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('vendor/adminlte/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css') }}">

@if(config('adminlte.plugins.datatables'))
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css">
@endif
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
```

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9t7mt.png) [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdWNN.png)

And here is the header and NavBar in other page , note that i have extended master page. I couldn't bring all the codes properly.

```
<header class="main-header">
        @if(config('adminlte.layout') == 'top-nav')
        <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a href="{{ url(config('adminlte.dashboard_url', 'home')) }}" class="navbar-brand">
                        {!! config('adminlte.logo', '<b>Admin</b>LTE') !!}
                    </a>
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-left" id="navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        @each('adminlte::partials.menu-item-top-nav', $adminlte->menu(), 'item')
                    </ul>
                </div>
        @else
        <div class="pull-left">
            <a href="{{ url(config('adminlte.dashboard_url', 'home')) }}" class="logo"  style="font-family: IRANSans;color: white; background-color:  #109e7a">
                <span class="logo-mini">{!! config('adminlte.logo_mini', '<b>A</b>LT') !!}</span>
                <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
                <span class="logo-lg">{!! config('adminlte.logo', '<b>Admin</b>LTE') !!}</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- Header Navbar -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
            <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
            <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="push-menu" role="button">
                <span class="sr-only">{{ trans('adminlte::adminlte.toggle_navigation') }}</span>
            </a>
        @endif
            <!-- Navbar Right Menu -->
            <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li style="font-family: IRANSans">
                        @if(config('adminlte.logout_method') == 'GET' || !config('adminlte.logout_method') && version_compare(\Illuminate\Foundation\Application::VERSION, '5.3.0', '<'))
                            <a href="{{ url(config('adminlte.logout_url', 'auth/logout')) }}">
                                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Exit
                            </a>
                        @else
                            <a href="#"
                               onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                Exit  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i>
                            </a>
                            <form id="logout-form" action="{{ url(config('adminlte.logout_url', 'auth/logout')) }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                @if(config('adminlte.logout_method'))
                                    {{ method_field(config('adminlte.logout_method')) }}
                                @endif
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                            </form>
                        @endif
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </nav>
            @if(config('adminlte.layout') == 'top-nav')
            </div>
            @endif
        </nav>
    </header>
```

When i added this link, navbar Exit Button disappears and the height of header increases..
**I'm new to html and css. Thank you for helping!**

Comment: Also post image of the design. How its being disarranged

Comment: I have added 2 images But i can't download them!